# Declare a Big Integer in C++

Tags: c++, factorial

I am trying to run this algorithm in c++ in order to get a big number

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num,factorial=1;
    cout<<" Enter Number To Find Its Factorial:  ";

    cin>>num;

    for(int a=1;a<=num;a++)
    {
       factorial=factorial*a;
    }

    cout<<"Factorial of Given Number is ="<<factorial<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I declare a Big Integer like in Java instead of an int?

Answer (score 2):

There is no big-integer support in the C++ standard library. A common choice for big-number arithmetic is [GMP](https://gmplib.org/). After downloading and installing the library, in your code you would `#include <gmpxx.h>` and declare `mpz_class factorial` instead of `int factorial`, then link against GMP.

Linking with GMP can be done in an IDE, by adding GMP in your editor’s compile settings; or by adding `-lgmp` to your compilation command (e.g., `g++` or `clang++`).

Answer (score 0):

There is no arbitrary-precision arithmetic in c++ standard library. You'll need to implement it yourself using an array of integers, or use an existing non-standard library.

Comment: So if I wanna declare a big integer I just add one of those libraries in my factorial class? i.e #include<BigInteger.hh> or whatnot?

Comment: @BehrouzHedayati yes, you'll need to include the headers which define the types that you're going to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try ***unsigned long long int*** for just convenience.

I just want to leave it as comment but I have low repu for commenting..

Answer (score 0):

There is **no standard support** for arbitrary-precision integers. However, a few **libraries** are available for handling big integers:

- [GNU MP Bignum Library](https://gmplib.org/)
- [InfInt](https://sercantutar.github.io/infint/)
- [C++ BigInt class](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/)
- [BigDigits multiple-precision arithmetic](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/bigdigits.html) (in C)
- [BigIntegerCPP](https://github.com/technophilis/BigIntegerCPP) (only supports addition and multiplication)
- [C++ Big Integer Library](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/) (no longer maintained)